# Why does s:iterator show only one result?

Tags: java, jdbc, struts2

I'd like to know why my iterator shows only one result from my jsp. Here's my code in s:iterator:

```
<s:iterator value="origins" var="items">
                    <s:select list="#items" label="Select origin" name="origin">
                    </s:select>
                </s:iterator>
```

And here's my code from action:

```
public class QueryAction{
private Sector sectorBean = null;
    private List<String> origins;
    private List<String> destinations;
public List<String> getOrigins() {
        return origins;
    }
    public void setOrigins(List<String> origins) {
        this.origins = origins;
    }
    public List<String> getDestinations() {
        return destinations;
    }
    public void setDestinations(List<String> destinations) {
        this.destinations = destinations;
    }
public String listing() {
        SectorDA sda = new SectorDAImpl();
        origins = sda.getOrigins();
        destinations = sda.getDestinations();
        return "success";
    }
}
```

The values of both origin and destination are : New York, New Orleans, Michigan, Memphis, Chicago, and Pittsburgh. And both only showed Chicago. Can anyone help me?

-UPDATE-

I've discovered why the iterator shows only one result. It's because of the class' corresponding DA. Here are the codes:

```
private static final String GET_ALL_SECTORS = "SELECT cSectorId, cOrigin, cDestination, cWeekDay1, cWeekDay2, mFirstClassFare, mBusinessClassFare, mEconomyClassFare FROM Sector";
@Override
    public List<Sector> getAllSectors() {
        List<Sector> sectors = new ArrayList<Sector>();
        Statement stat = null;
        try {
            stat = DatabaseConnector.getConnection().createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery(GET_ALL_SECTORS);
            if(rs.next()) {
                String sectorId = rs.getString(1);
                String origin = rs.getString(2);
                String destination = rs.getString(3);
                String weekDay1 = rs.getString(4);
                String weekDay2 = rs.getString(5);
                BigDecimal fcFare = rs.getBigDecimal(6);
                BigDecimal bcFare = rs.getBigDecimal(7);
                BigDecimal ecFare = rs.getBigDecimal(8);

                Sector e = new Sector(sectorId, origin, destination, weekDay1, weekDay2, fcFare, bcFare, ecFare);
                sectors.add(e);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(stat != null) {
                try {
                    stat.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return sectors;
    }
```

Please help me.

Comment: Why do you think `<s:select>` tag attribute `list` is named like that? You don't need an iterator.

Comment: It's my idea of listing down the options to the <s:select> tag.

Comment: Please read the docs on how to use specific tags before posting this kind of questions.

Comment: A select tag's list should be a collection, or iterator.